# const layer = svg.match(re)[0]; TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Tags: javascript

I have this code that lays 3 different svgs over each other to form one svg, but I keep getting an error. Please help, thank you :)

```
function getLayer(name, skip=0.0) {
    const svg = readFileSync(`./layers/${name}.svg`, 'utf-8');
    const re = /(?<=\<svg\s*[^>]*>)([\s\S]*?)(?=\<\/svg\>)/g
    const layer = svg.match(re)[0];
    return Math.random() > skip ? layer : '';
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far to debug? You should take a look at the content of `svg` and the return value of `svg.match(re)`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is yhe file you are trying to read is not matched with the regex you provided.
you can gaurd your code like the followig:

```js
function getLayer(name, skip=0.0) {
    const svg = readFileSync(`./layers/${name}.svg`, 'utf-8');
    const re = /(?<=\<svg\s*[^>]*>)([\s\S]*?)(?=\<\/svg\>)/g
    const res = svg.match(re);
    return res?.length && Math.random() > skip ? res[0] : ''
}
```

otherwise you should check your input file for invalid svg matches